# Can't launch selenium tests via selenese

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

When I launch selenese via this command :

> java -jar selenese-runner.jar -d chrome --chromedriver chromedriver.exe -b http://localhost:8080 C:\Trunk\src\selenium\suiteTest

I get this error :

```
[2017-11-30 11:02:36.722 +01:00] [ERROR]jp.vmi.selenium.selenese.SeleneseRunnerRuntimeException: No such command: Build info: version: '3.5.3', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown' System info: host: 'WALOX', ip: '10.1.85.3', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version:'1.8.0_121'
```

I launch it in a folder that contains selenese-runner.jarv3.8.0 and a chromeDriver.exe v2.33.506120

This is all the stack just in case :

```
[2017-11-30 11:02:33.218 +01:00] [INFO] Start: Selenese Runner 3.8.0
Starting ChromeDriver 2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f) on port 12619
Only local connections are allowed.
[2017-11-30 11:02:36.293 +01:00] [INFO] Detected dialect: OSS
[2017-11-30 11:02:36.300 +01:00] [INFO] Initial window size: system default
[2017-11-30 11:02:36.300 +01:00] [INFO] Initialized: ChromeDriver
[2017-11-30 11:02:36.308 +01:00] [INFO] Override base URL: http://localhost:8080
[2017-11-30 11:02:36.313 +01:00] [INFO] Timeout: 30000 ms
[2017-11-30 11:02:36.674 +01:00] [INFO] Start: TestSuite[suiteTest] (C:\Trunk\src\selenium\suiteTest)
[2017-11-30 11:02:36.712 +01:00] [INFO] Existing driver found.
[2017-11-30 11:02:36.720 +01:00] [INFO] Current speed: 0 ms/command
[2017-11-30 11:02:36.722 +01:00] [ERROR] jp.vmi.selenium.selenese.SeleneseRunnerRuntimeException: No such command:
Build info: version: '3.5.3', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'WALOX', ip: '10.1.85.3', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
[2017-11-30 11:02:36.724 +01:00] [INFO] End(0,000sec): TestSuite[suiteTest] (C:\Trunk\src\selenium\suiteTest)
[2017-11-30 11:02:36.724 +01:00] [INFO] Exit code: 3
[2017-11-30 11:02:37.430 +01:00] [INFO] Quit: ChromeDriver
```

I've looked on the net. It seems that I am the only person with this error in the world. I have no clue!

Comment: Irespective of you being the `only person with this error in the world`:) the error seems loud & clear `SeleneseRunnerRuntimeException: No such command` Try looking at the arguments acceptable to **`selenese-runner.jar`**

Comment: can you post your suiteTest class code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RESOLVED

In fact it was so stupid! I am using Selenium IDE on firefox to write the test, and I ve added an empty command line at the end which generate an empty entry in the generated HTML :

```
   <tr> 
      <td></td> 
      <td></td> 
      <td></td> 
   </tr>
```

Which made the script to fail on this error!